# Does a ballista fire automatically?

Tags: timber-and-stone

In Timber & stone, does a ballista manned by an infantry fire at targets on its own, or do I still have to aim and fire it manually? It is pretty hard to do this, so being able to auto-fire would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the creator says:

> Siege equipment will always require player interaction, so aiming and preferences are set when selecting the ballista by left clicking.

In the [change log for 0.9b](http://www.timberandstonegame.com/?p=422).

Comment: wonder how this is going to work for actual battles, that the creator has mentioned wanting to have in the game.